# Do laptops have Bluetooth interface by default?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, dell-latitude

I'm trying to connect my Dell Latitude `E5450` Windows 10 to home audio system via Bluetooth.

I'm wondering where a Bluetooth icon in tray bar is. Do laptops support Bluetooth interface by default or should I buy a USB dongle?

Comment: Read the [spec](http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-latitude-e5450-14-core-i5-5300u-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd/specs/) for your laptop. "Wireless Protocol 802.11ac, Bluetooth 4.0"

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) pre-made computing devices (PCs, laptops, cellphones, tablets, etc) have built-in bluetooth.
As to your question, AFAIK, you need to *enable* bluetooth for the icon to appear in the system tray. Try pressing <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> which should call up the Windows Mobility Center (unless MS removed that feature of late). From there, you'll see if bluetooth is enabled. If the bluetooth adaptor isn't listed, it's probably hadblocked or there's a driver not correctly installed.
Assuming first that it's hardblocked, look for the button on your keyboard with a wireless(wifi/bluetooth) icon and press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + that button to try and turn BT on (it should toggle WIFI+BT, WIFI, BT, NONE). Failing that, try reinstalling the drivers provided by your OEM.